# Simpler way to order facet_wrap plot by year

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have 20 years of weight data and I want to make a 10 rows by 2 columns facet_wrap figure with ggplot2. The problem is that I want to re-order the facets in such a way that I have the first ten years in the left column and the last 10 years in the right column.

I could re-order the levels manually as suggested in other posts but this is rather painful. Also, I'll have to reorder the levels again if I want to do the same thing but with different years.

Is there an easier way ? Here's an example to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
sub.data$year = factor(sub.data$year, 
                       levels = c(2000,2005,2001,2006,2002,2007,2003,2008,2004,2009...))

ggplot(data = sub.data, aes(x = sub.data$weight)) +
  geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ year, ncol = 2)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `dir = "v"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(year = rep(2001:2020, 5), x = runif(100), y = runif(100))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~year, ncol = 2, dir = "v")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Ah! How could I miss this ?